# MikTex doesn't open and returns an error message

Tags: package-management

I have Miktex installed and it worked just fine. All of a sudden I
keep getting an error message. I have not deleted anything from my system
[the top right window is what I get from MikTex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJuwI.png).
Can anyone help me with this problem.
Thanks.